# Is the experience of God the fulfillment of all our desires here...or an unknown quantity?

Tags: nature-of-god, heaven

I love the British sci-fi series 'Dr Who'... also films, movie monsters and statues of film characters, film collectables and so on...some love golf...others flower arranging etc.

Now I've heard it said that loves like these are shadows, echoes or reflections of God and that, through seeing Him, our ultimate want in EVERYTHING desirable will be complete.

Before anyone tells me, I don't mean that this means we should worship our enjoyments AS God (nor should we allow such things to cause ill- drink may be good but too much equals drunkenness (as an example)).

Is this idea correct? Are our joys 'sunbeams' to God's 'Sun'? Or is the experience of God (Beatification) completely other to ANYTHING here, not just by degree of satifaction in relation to Him but also 'type' experience?

Before this sends anyones alarm bells ringing, I'm not asking for an opinion, merely what the Church tends to think as regards this question; "it doesn't" or "it depends from person to person WHAT is believed as regards this" are perfectly good answers.

Comment: These are the sort of questions I'd really like answers to. if this site is not the right place then can someone please direct me to another that is? This seems to be one of the few reliable sites on Christianity on the web...yet the questions must be so specific I can never ask what I truly wish to know...Please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Might icecream be a 'sunbeam' of God or a 'signpost' pointing at God?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/might-icecream-be-a-sunbeam-of-god-or-a-signpost-pointing-at-god)

Answer (score 2):

On the basis of I Corinthians 2: 9-10, I would expect that the joy of heaven is beyond anything we can imagine naturally, and therefore far beyond anything we can experience in this life, but that we can understand it, at least to some degree, through God's revelation.

Comment: But after "Eye hath not seen..." it goes on to say that it has been revealed to us, so, in other words, "We had no way of knowing until He showed us."

Comment: @ThomasJennings That's exactly what I meant in the last 14 words of my answer and why I wrote "naturally" earlier in my answer.

Comment: Sorry! Is the revelation in the Bible a symbolic acount...so 'gold roads' might mean joyful riches, in wich case joys now might be a foretaste of that?

Comment: @ThomasJennings I think material descriptions like "gold roads" are symbolic hints, written in terms that we can imagine, about a reality that surpasses our imaginative abilities. More abstract descriptions, like "perfect happiness", probably come closer to expressing the reality, but they probably lack (for most people) the emotional impact of more concrete descriptions. The ultimate joy of heaven will consist of the contemplation of God Himself, and I don't see any way for a concrete or material description to come close to that.